# CSS styling of pygments HTML

Tags: python, html, css, alignment, pygments

I used the Python library pygments to pygmentized some code to put it on a website I created.
I've seen many websites displaying code, but when the code contains a long line, the overflow is simply hidden. I dislike it being hidden and want to make the container scrollable. However, when I add the CSS rules:

```
.highlighttable {
    margin: auto;
    max-width: 75vw;
}

.highlighttable .code {
    max-width: calc(74vw - 100px);
    overflow: auto;
}
```

The whole thing looks like this:

[image: Screenshot]

I guess the following is happening here:

- The scrollbar is calculated into the size of the `.code` div element.
- The size of the `.code` containing div grew
- the div containing the line numbers is somehow vertically in the middle

So I tried to add the following CSS rules:

```
.linenodiv {
    vertical-align: top;
}

.linenodiv pre {
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

But to no awail, the line number div is still shifted as shown in the screenshot. The following is the HTML code for the whole table:

```
<table class="highlighttable">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td class="linenos">
                <div class="linenodiv">
                    <pre>1
2
3
4
5
6</pre>

                </div>
            </td>
            <td class="code">
                <div class="highlight">
                    <pre><span class="k">class</span> <span class="nc">TestClass</span><span class="p">:</span>
<span class="k">def</span> <span class="nf">__init__</span><span class="p">(</span><span class="bp">self</span><span class="p">):</span>
<span class="k">pass</span>

<span class="k">def</span> <span class="nf">test_method</span><span class="p">(</span><span class="bp">self</span><span class="p">,</span> <span class="n">arg1</span><span class="p">,</span> <span class="n">arg1</span><span class="p">,</span> <span class="n">arg1</span><span class="p">):</span>
<span class="k">print</span><span class="p">(</span><span class="n">arg1</span><span class="p">)</span>
</pre>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I reduced the number of `arg1`s in this code, because it's only to show the structure of the html code.

How can I shift the line number div back up?

**EDIT#1**

Here is a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vh8eL841/1/)

It seems jsfiddle doesn't handle the css overflow property the same way Firefox on my computer does. jsfiddle doesn't render scrollbars for `overflow: auto;` at all and the issue is not visible there. Instead it jst writes the text outside of the div, as if there was an `overflow: visible;`

Comment: Please, can you show us a fiddle? :)

Comment: @PDKnight: Did that. However, there are issues with jsfiddle not rendering any scrollbar.

Comment: Can you please [join the chatroom](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/99631/room-for-pdknight-and-zelphir)? :)

Answer (score 1):

The issue was that I didn't apply

```
vertical-align: top;
```

to the correct element. I now applied it to the `td` with the class `.linenos` as visible here: [enter link description here](http://jsfiddle.net/vh8eL841/4)

Thanks @PDKnight, your input made me check what happens when I apply it to that td element.